# Sort vector of vector using generic function

Tags: c++, generics, vector

I'm trying to make a function which will sort rows of vector of vector using std::sort function from algorithm library. Function must be generic. And comparison criterion is sum of row elements. Function for comparing which will be used in std::sort function also must be generic.

EXAMPLE

```
2 5 1 3 4 
9 8 9
3 3 2 3
4 5 2 1 1 3 2
```

After sorting:

```
9 8 9
4 5 2 1 1 3 2
2 5 1 3 4
3 3 2 3
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
template<typename tip>
auto Compare(std::vector<tip>&a, std::vector<tip>&b) {
  auto sum_a = 0, sum_b = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    sum_a += a[i];
  for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
    sum_b += b[i];
  return sum_a > sum_b;
}
template <typename tip>
void sort_sum_of_rows(std::vector<std::vector<tip>> &mat) {
  std::sort(mat.begin(), mat.end(), Compare);
}
int main() {
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> a{{2, 5, 1, 3, 4},
    {9, 8, 9},
    {3, 3, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2}};
  sort_sum_of_rows(a);
  for (auto &v : a) {
    for (int j : v)
      std::cout << j << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

ERRORS (line 15):

> no matching function for call to ‘sort(std::vector >::iterator,
> std::vector >::iterator, )’
>
> template argument deduction/substitution failed: main.cpp:15:12: note:
> candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided

Could you help me to fix my function Compare?

Comment: Does `sum_b += a[i];` make sense to you if this is read outloud, in plain words? If you are allegedly trying to calculate something called a "sum (of) b", what does adding up all the `a` values accomplish towards that goal? VTC as a typo.

Comment: that was accidental mistake, sorry

Comment: `std::sort(mat.begin(), mat.end(), Compare<tip>);` Note the explicit template parameter for `Compare`

Comment: `sort_sum_of_rows(a);`  does nothing because `a` is a copy. The copy gets sorted then discarded. The original is unchanged. Use a reference.

Comment: thanks, I added reference, but I have problem with function Compare. Could you help me to fix it? I added errors in question.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that solved problem, could you add your answer? I would accept it